# What does it mean to for a function to have a "constant, relative" rate of change?

Tags: calculus

The function $f(x) = Ae^{kx}$, where $A$ and $k$ are positive constants is said to have "constant, relative" rate of change.

How does it differ from the statement that it has a constant rate of change?

Thanks,

Comment: Since the function is an exponential function, it satisfies the property $f' = kf$. In other words, the rate of change is a constant times the current value. I think that's why it's 'relative' to its own value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the rate of change, relative to the actual value, is constant. It always increases (or decreases) by a fixed percentage in a given time interval.

Answer (score 1):

The function $y=mx$ has a **constant rate of change** $y'=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=m$ (for $\Delta x \to 0$).This means that the rate of change $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ is the same for any value of $x$. It is a linear function.

Your function is such that **the rate of change at a point divided by the value of the function at this point** is constant: $\frac{y'}{y}= k$. The function satisfies the differential equation $y'=ky$. So you can see that the rate of change at a point is proportional to the value of the function at this point.   It is an exponential function.